# retrieving complete windows phone debug output

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking for a way to capture all output coming from my device (similar to what adb (without any filter) does for android). Is there any way to retrieve this information? Visual studios seems to be returning only a select set of the output, and only from the application being tested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could have your own logger mechanism, with file write.

Comment: I would love to make something like this, but how can i capture all usb output from the device?

Comment: in this case you will not be able to take output at runtime . on app shutdown you can have all logs written in one file. just get that file at the end.

Comment: you mean the .spl file which the .sap file in my project points to? I tried opening that but it wasn't readable... :/